# Multiple user profiles/accounts in an app - Persistence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

How to implement multiple user accounts/profiles in an app? I use Core Data in my project and I don't know how to design my model. Should I make a NSPersistentStore for every user or what? Or make some top-level entity ?

Comment: Question is pretty straight forward. Let's say that I have an app for example a Facebook client. How should I design data model correctly when I want to have multiple user accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a top level entity `UserSession` and store all messages, friends etc. below that. Now you can filter everything by some attribute of `UserSession`, such as `userID`.